Wordpress and php 8.1
I am trying to run wordpress 6.7.1 on ubuntu 24.04 with nginx and php8.1-fpm.
This is a fresh wordpress install with theme Twenty Twenty-Five and no plugins installed.
I also disabled any cache.
I am noticing very unstable behavior. Pages are displayed incorrectly or only partially.
Is wordpress really running with php8.1?

Yes, with minor caveats which would not explain the described behaviors. There is likely some configuration issue with your hosting environment or installation

Yes, I know the published statements by Automattic very well. But the reality is different. It's very simple. Take an Ubuntu 22.04 with a standard installation of Apache and PHP and you will find that it does not work. The statement that it is due to the configuration is irrelevant because if it takes 100 hours for this unusual installation, it is as good as if it does not work. And by the way, nobody has been able to show me a working Wordpress site with PHP 8 yet.

56.7% of WordPress sites phoning home to .org are running on top of PHP 8. I just failed to reproduce the described behaviors on a barebones LAMP with WP 6.7.1 and PHP 8.1.2 on an Ubuntu 24.04 DO Droplet with 1 gig of RAM - everything loads and operates as expected. Snappier than I remember, even. If you still believe WP to be the culprit you could file a Trac ticket - I would have myself, had I managed to reproduce the behaviors. Short of that, I suggest asking in a more general community, and including more details.

That doesn't help me at all. I don't want WordPress hosted on DigitalOcean, and I assume most WordPress users don't either. For me, at least, WordPress does not work with PHP 8.0, 8.1, or 8.2 when using the PHP repository https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/. I've tried this multiple times with different ubuntu  and wordpress versions, and as soon as I switch to PHP 7.4, everything works without any issues.

All I am saying is that I spent an hour trying to reproduce your issue as you described it by setting up a LAMP stack on a VPS from scratch and I could not. I did not change any of Ubuntu's package repositories and cannot divine why your situation would be different. There isn't enough information here for anyone else to guess at a solution either - though hosting and environment configuration issues are off-topic here, anyway. I wish you the best of luck in resolving the matter - I've never seen it before and have no idea what it could be.

The only deviation from a minimal LAMP stack that I can think of was the installation of several of the PHP modules which .org recommends. But by and far, my installation experience with PHP 8 is the norm for hundreds of people daily. Your experience is the anomalous exception. I'd check client-side network logs, server logs, WP Site Health, WP debugging output. Include that information and insights in your question. A detailed step-by-step of your procedure would probably be the most constructive thing. Images/videos may help as well. Or try an install script, or switch to managed/a container

After hours of investigation and heavy testing I found the reason.
Uninstall the php-extension php8.1-uopz changed everything.
It seems uopz will break every wordpress.
I hope this information will help others not to install it.
Thanks to Bosco, he made me take a closer look at this issue.
